# Install packages during build of rocker/tidyverse docker image

Tags: r, docker

I am building a docker image using [rocker/tidyverse](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse).

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:4.0.4

COPY train.R /train.R
COPY install.R /install.R
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# pre install the packages during build
RUN Rscript install.R
```

Here's the `install.r` script from above:

```
install.packages('pacman')
pacman::p_load(lubridate, Metrics, foreach)
```

Also tried a variation of this with just `install.packages(<packagename>)` for each of the packages in the install.r script.

When I attempt to build I get an error message:

```
docker-compose build rtrain

Step 5/5 : RUN Rscript install.R
 ---> Running in 3ebf7ab0c227
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/2021-03-30/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/2021-03-30/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package 'pacman' is not available for this version of R
```

If I remove  `RUN Rscript install.r` from build but instead run the image and then exec into it, I am able to run it with just `Rsctipt install.r`. It's only during build that this happens.

On the page on the first url I linked to above there's a mention of script `install2.r` but I could not find any mention of this anywhere. The full blurb:

> > NOTES
>
> - **do not use `apt-get install r-cran-*` to install R packages on this stack** . The requested R version and all R packages are installed from source in the version-stable stack. Installing R packages from `apt` (e.g. the `r-cran-*` packages) will install the version of R and versions of the packages that were built for the stable debian release (e.g. `debian:stretch` ), giving you a second version of R and different packages. Please install R packages from source using the `install.packages()` R function (or the `install2.r` script), and use `apt` only to install necessary system libraries (e.g. `libxml2` ). If you would prefer to install only the latest verions of packages from pre-built binaries using `apt-get` , consider using the `r-base` stack instead.

Underlining I did try modifying install.r to just be repeated rows of `install.packages("lubridate")` `install.packages("Metrics")` and `install.packages("foreach")` but the same error happens.

How can I install packages during build using this image?

Comment: Hi @camille thanks for the suggestion, but looking at my actual code that was a typo during posting the q, my actual code uses both `COPY install.R /install.R` and then `RUN Rscript install.R` :/

When you say "I'm pretty sure the rocker images come with a install.r" could you elaborate? I could not see that anywhere or how to use it?

Comment: I misspoke about `install.r`, it's `/rocker_scripts/install_R.sh` which each image runs. See https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/d734a85bc8ef761797049eff9b4fccfa948f61e7/dockerfiles/r-ver_4.1.1.Dockerfile#L18

Comment: Thanks camille! Please hold my hand here. I see `RUN /rocker_scripts/install_R.sh` on the link you shared. But I don't see how to use it? What/where do I type to add the 3 packages?!

Comment: Sorry, I think between the 2 github repos and the docker hub repo I'm confusing both of us! I've found it helpful to see what the rocker images run when you build upon them. The tidyverse image runs a script `install_tidyverse.sh` (https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/d734a85bc8ef761797049eff9b4fccfa948f61e7/dockerfiles/tidyverse_4.1.1.Dockerfile#L8), which in turn calls `install2.r` (https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/d734a85bc8ef761797049eff9b4fccfa948f61e7/scripts/install_tidyverse.sh#L21) from littler

Comment: Hmm. I tried adding a block to my Dockerfile mimicking that example: `RUN install2.r --error --skipinstalled -n $NCPUS \
    lubridate \
    Metrics \
    foreach`

Same error though :/

Answer (score 1):

Changing my version to 4.0.1 solved my problem:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:4.0.1
```

Then everything else the same, worked.